# Level up after maxing out character's attributes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I've maxed out my character's attributes, but still have a few levels' worth of major skill points to earn. When I try to level up, I get a message saying perfection cannot be improved upon, no level up dialog and the level up icon remains in the HUD. Can I still level up somehow?

Comment: what platform? are you opposed to console commands?

Comment: @ColinD PC and no, I'm not. I hope the answer will cover all platforms.

Comment: What level are you?

Comment: @Mandemon 46, why?

Comment: Wondered if you had hit the insane level cap of 255. Clearly not. After checking around, you can't because once attributes hit the max game won't allow you to level up anymore. Still looking if there is a way around this, a console command or mod.

Comment: Even though there may be no satisfying answer, this question itself is a valuable heads-up. Knowing that there may be a problem, others can count the number of possible levelups and earn them in a way so that the stats max out with the last level, even if that means "wasting" stat points earlier.

Answer (score 3):

If your attributes are all at maximum, the game won't allow you to level up any further, giving you the message you received.

Temporary solution is to use a mod to increase the attribute caps:

http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=OblivionMods.Detail&id=3470

Source(s)

- http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Leveling
- http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Character_Level#Attribute_and_stat_increase

Comment: `advlevel` acts the same as sleeping, I get the message about perfection, my level stays the same and the level up icon is still present in the HUD.

Comment: Then it's mods or advskill.

Comment: How is `advskill` supposed to help? I've already earned a level up fairly.

Comment: I think I got some stuff mixed up, let me see... Yeah, got stuff confused. In your case, it does not help. So that leaves mods.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of any mods that let me level up without increasing my attributes and skills beyond 100? I don't want to unbalance the game too much.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is a mod that introduces some changes to the leveling: http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=OblivionMods.Detail&id=334 However, I cannot comment how good it is or if it even is useful for you.

Comment: Can't you just reduce the stats with a modding command? And then raise them back when levelling up?

Comment: Stats, yes. Just go to prison. However, in this case, problem is that stats are not maxed, but attributes. You can't decrease attributes.